# Where can I get a windows version of bibtex.exe?

Tags: bibtex, windows

I need BibTeX for use with a tool that requires it. I do not need any of the other parts of TeX, so the TeX Live distribution is massive overkill. Where can I get a compiled Windows binary of BibTeX?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest would be to download it from the TeX Live SVN, where it contains the list of [Windows binaries](http://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/bin/win32/). Specifically, there you will find [`bibtex.exe`](http://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/bin/win32/bibtex.exe?view=log).

Comment: Thanks so much for this, it turned out to be exactly what I needed. I had no idea the binaries would be in the SVN repo. Took a little while to figure out I also needed kpathsea622.dll because the tool I was using did not report the startup error. Running it from the command line pointed out the problem. Now I just need to figure out whether I really want to be using bibtex or some of the newer ones like Bibulous, Biber, or Bibtex8.